# ASP.NET Core razor pages - generate route conditionally with asp-route-

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've implemented routing based localization for my asp.net core project (.NET 8). Basically, these requirements are met:

- when the root is requested ( path = ***'/'*** ) the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is set to `ru-RU`
- when the root is requested as ***'/en'*** the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is set to `en-US`
- for the default culture, when ***'/ru'*** is requested (or ***'/ru/[whatever]'***) the request returns "moved permanently (301)" with location set to ***'/'*** (or ***'/[whatever]'*** respectively)

But when I generage a link to home page with:

```
<a asp-page="/Index" asp-route-lang="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">Home</a>
```

I get `https://localhost/ru` for the default culture (ru-RU), and `https://localhost/en` for English (en-US).

Question:

> How can I get rid of `/ru` part when generating a URL for default culture (instead of having `https://localhost/ru` I need to get just `https://localhost`). I can use a condition in every `asp-route-lang="..."` but that is not a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that this can be done to remove the default culture (route path) in the route via the custom tag helper.

As the below, you can compare the value of the `asp-route-lang` attribute against the default culture of your application. If both values are same, you overwrite the `href` attribute.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;

[HtmlTargetElement("a")]
public class AnchorWithLangTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-route-lang")]
    public string Lang { get; set; }

    private readonly RequestLocalizationOptions _options;

    public AnchorWithLangTagHelper(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Remove the Lang from route if provided Lang is default culture 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Lang)
            && _options.DefaultRequestCulture.UICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(Lang, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var generatedHref = output.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString();
            generatedHref = generatedHref.Replace($"/{Lang}/", "/");

            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", generatedHref);
        }
    }
}
```

And add the custom tag helper to make it available in all views via [`@addTagHelper` in the *Views/_ViewImport.cshtml*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0#addtaghelper-makes-tag-helpers-available).

```
@addTagHelper <Namespace of AnchorWithLangTagHelper>.AnchorWithLangTagHelper, <Project Namespace>
```

> Demo

[image]

Comment: Bro, where are you based in?

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron, I am from Malaysia. 

Comment: I've been watching your post since long and its really nice... Is there any way to connect you bro?

Comment: You are welcome @AlexB, good to see my answer helps.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron, here is my [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/kok-yong-shun-599259167) if you would like to connect. Thanks.